# Guardar estado de un fragmento

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenas, tengo la duda que todo programador en Android tuvo en sus inicios xD

Tengo una actividad en la cual al iniciarse se carga un fragmento en ella, después ese fragmento cambiará por otro en función de un `Drawermenu`. 
Bueno pues hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema está cuando giro la pantalla y peta la aplicación. He estado investigando y se que hay que trabajar con el `onSaveInstanceState()` etc pero no consigo hacerlo. No se si tengo que hacerlo en la actividad padre o en los fragmentos =/ o si en los dos tengo que hacer algo.

¿Cómo tendría que hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En [Manejo de cambios en tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) de la documentación Android explica un poco el proceso que debes seguir para controlar los cambios de orientación o de configuración.

Para tu caso con Fragments creo que en el enlace de la documentación está muy bien explicado cómo gestionar este proceso. Lo gestiona utilizando `setRetainInstance(boolean)`

Una forma de controlar los giros de pantallas en las Activity es la siguiente:

En el manifest declaras los cambios que quieres controlar mediante la etiqueta `android:configChanges`, quedando la declaración de la actividad de la siguiente forma:

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppThemeAction" />
```

Y luego el código que se pone en el activity para recoger los eventos de cambio de configuración como puede ser el cambio de orientación de la pantalla es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    //detectamos el cambio de orientación en este caso
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        landscape = true;
        //acciones deseadas
    }

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        landscape = false;
        //acciones deseadas
    }
}
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias ! Ni sabía que existía eso xD

Comment: Espero te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: No pude probarlo hasta ahora jjj pero me funciona perfectamente y sin necesidad de sobreescribir el metodo `onConfigurationChanged()` xD solamente escribiendo `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`en el manifiesto me funciona perfectamente. Por cierto, es importante porner `orientation|screenSize` porque al cambiar la orientación de la pantalla cambia el tamaño también, por tanto hay que poner ambas.  Muchas gracias !

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido!!!